# How do I run a vim script that alters the current buffer?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a beautify.vim script that makes C-like code adhere to a standard that I can easily read.

My file contains only substitution commands that all begin with `%s/...`

However, when I try to run the script with my file open, in the manner `:source beautify.vim`, or `:runtime beautify.vim`, it runs but all the substitute commands state that their pattern wasn't found (patterns were tested by entering them manually and should work).

Is there some way to make vim run the commands in the context of the current buffer?

beautify.vim:

```
" add spaces before open braces
sil! :%s/\%>1c\s\@<!{/ {/g
" beautify for
sil! :%s/for *( *\([^;]*\) *; *\([^;]*\) *; *\([^;]*\) *)/for (\1; \2; \3)/
" add spaces after commas
sil! :%s/,\s\@!/, /g
```

In my tests the first :s command should match (it matches when applied manually).

Comment: Use `:source beautify.vim` from inside a C file will run your script with the 'current buffer' being your C file, unless you are somehow switching buffers inside your script? You may need to include the source code to your beautify.vim script (or at least up to the first `%s` that doesn't work.

Comment: @Jeremiah: [e] option: "do not issue an error message, and, in particular, continue in maps as if no error occurred." - so seems not to apply to scripts. Proof of which is that when running the script as mentioned I get an error for each `:s` that failed, meaning that vim evaluates all of them. My solution after making it work would've been to add `:silent` to each `:s` command, which probably works just as well as the [e] option.

Comment: Never mind. Found it to be working after finding that the :s that should've matched had an extra character.

Answer (score 3):

I just recently wrote a similar beautifier script but I implemented it in what I think is a more flexible way; plus, I tried to come up with a mechanism to avoid substituting stuff within strings.

```
" {{{ regex silly beautifier (avoids strings, works with ranges)
function! Foo_SillyRegexBeautifier(start, end)

    let i = a:start
    while i <= a:end
        let line = getline(i)

        " ignore preprocessor directives
        if match(line, '^\s*#') == 0
            let i += 1
            continue
        endif

        " ignore content of strings, splitting at double quotes characters not 
        " preceded by escape characters
        let chunks = split(line, '\(\([^\\]\|^\)\\\(\\\\\)*\)\@<!"', 1)

        let c = 0
        for c in range(0, len(chunks), 2)

            let chunk = chunks[c]
            " add whitespace in couples
            let chunk = substitute(chunk, '[?({\[,]', '\0 ', 'g')
            let chunk = substitute(chunk, '[?)}\]]', ' \0', 'g')

            " continue like this by calling substitute() on chunk and 
            " reassigning it
            " ...

            let chunks[c] = chunk
        endfor

        let line = join(chunks, '"')

        " remove spaces at the end of the line
        let line = substitute(line, '\s\+$', '', '')

        call setline(i, line)

        let i += 1
    endw
endfunction
" }}}
```

Then I define a mapping that affects the whole file in normal mode, and only the selected lines in visual mode. This is good when you have some carefully formatted parts of the file that you don't want to touch.

```
nnoremap ,bf :call Foo_SillyRegexBeautifier(0, line('$'))<CR>
vnoremap ,bf :call Foo_SillyRegexBeautifier(line("'<"), line("'>"))<CR>
```

Comment: This is actually pretty useful, especially if you add single operators and stuff like that (`\(?:\1\)\@<!\([+-*/]\)=?`). And also it should take into account already existing spaces so that you only convert 0-more spaces into one in those places.